# Routing Angular with subpaths

Tags: angular, routes

I need to create an Angular application that has a root URL like "domain.com/hub/language".

"hub" and "language" are dynamically populated.

And when I access the "login" page, for example, the url must be "domain.com/hub/language/login".

What is the correct way to configure this array of routes and what is the correct way to navigate between routes? For example:

```
this._router.navigate(['login']);
```

I tried the code below, but it doesn't work in my case.

```
export const appRoutes: Route[] = [
  {
    path: ':hub/:language/',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadComponent: () => LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'sign-up',
        loadComponent: () => SignupComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadComponent: () => HomeBaseComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'news',
        loadComponent: () => NewsComponent
      }
    ]
  },

];
```

Answer (score 1):

loadComponent() lazy loads standalone component:

```
loadComponent: () => import('./login/login.component').then(c => c.LoginComponent)
```

and route with:

```
this._router.navigate([:hub, :language, 'login'])
```

or route with HTML directive:

```html
<a [routerLink]="[:hub, :language, 'login']">
```

*Replace :hub and :language with the dynamic data*

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought there was a way to not need to pass "hub" and "language" throughout the navigation, by defining a root route, but in this case I'm going to create a service or helper for that.

Comment: Ok. Then try relative path navigation: `this._router.navigate(['./login'])` or `[routerLink]="['./login']"`